# Silverlight out of browser icons displaying inconsistently

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, out-of-browser

I'm getting some strange behaviour with the out of browser icons in a Silverlight 3 app. All four sizes are defined in the AppManifest.xml and each icon has the build action set to "Content". However, I'm only seeing the icon display on the very first install prompt (128x128 icon) and not on the desktop, shortcut menu or title bar when the app runs. If I remove the 128x128 icon definition from the xml then the next size down is automatically used so it seems they're all being referenced and packaged correctly.

Here's the app manifest xml:

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Deployment.ApplicationIdentity>
        <ApplicationIdentity ShortName="XXX" Title="XXX">
            <ApplicationIdentity.Blurb>XXX</ApplicationIdentity.Blurb>
            <ApplicationIdentity.Icons>
                <Icon Size="16x16">Icons/16.png</Icon>
                <Icon Size="32x32">Icons/32.png</Icon>
                <Icon Size="48x48">Icons/48.png</Icon>
                <Icon Size="128x128">Icons/128.png</Icon>
            </ApplicationIdentity.Icons>
        </ApplicationIdentity>
    </Deployment.ApplicationIdentity>
</Deployment>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Good question. Did you post this on the official forums? It might be a bug that needs fixing on the RTM release :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference, the out of browser configuration has changed for the release version of Silverlight 3. The settings are now configured in OutOfBrowserSettings.xml and read as follows:

```
<OutOfBrowserSettings ShortName="XXX" EnableGPUAcceleration="False" ShowInstallMenuItem="True">
  <OutOfBrowserSettings.Blurb>XXX</OutOfBrowserSettings.Blurb>
  <OutOfBrowserSettings.WindowSettings>
    <WindowSettings Title="XXX" Height="800" Width="600" />
  </OutOfBrowserSettings.WindowSettings>
  <OutOfBrowserSettings.Icons>
    <Icon Size="16,16">Icons/16.png</Icon>
    <Icon Size="32,32">Icons/32.png</Icon>
    <Icon Size="48,48">Icons/48.png</Icon>
    <Icon Size="128,128">Icons/128.png</Icon>
  </OutOfBrowserSettings.Icons>
</OutOfBrowserSettings>
```

This has solved all the problems I described above. Further info on the changes in the release version are here: http://blogs.msdn.com/katriend/archive/2009/07/10/silverlight-3-out-of-browser-applications.aspx